# NPM packages for Next.js - do they need to be in ES5?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

I'm bundling a bunch of components I regularly use in apps I create with Next.js into an npm package to make it easier to reuse them between projects, however I'm having difficulty getting it to work.

The big issue I have is that some of my components need to import/require a configuration file from the project root directory (e.g. `project/node_modules/mypackage/index.[js/jsx/tsx]` needs to import/require `project/config.[js/ts]`) so I need to ensure the app is able to import components from the npm package, and the npm package is able to import/require from the app.

I use Typescript to compile the npm package (no Webpack or Babel) but I'm not sure what settings to use for target, lib, module and jsx, or if I'm able to just keep it uncompiled as .tsx and .ts files (I'm using the canary branch of Next.js which has built-in Typescript support).

I can't find any information in the documentation, here on SO or via Google search. Any advice?

Comment: For writing modules in typescript (and importable to typescript) you can check out this article: https://codeburst.io/https-chidume-nnamdi-com-npm-module-in-typescript-12b3b22f0724. Unfortunately you need to publish compiled sources

Comment: Also.. `npm package is able to import/require from the app` -- DON'T DO THIS! In **any** language. Use dependency injection instead (you don't need a framework, just pass your dependencies to your module's constructor or init function)

Comment: There are plenty of packages that do this without dependency injection. Such as Typescript (with tsconfig.json), Next.js (with next.config.js), Babel (with .babelrc), etc.

Comment: Compiling it is no issue. I see in that link they use es5 and commonjs. No mention of jsx or library though so I guess they just use the defaults.

Comment: Those packages usually don't simply require config files. Instead they have logic to check for existence of config files then load them. This is common. I typically use the `config` or `rc` module for this. (`rc` is especially nice for *nix apps because it automatically checks in /etc and your home directory for config files)